# How to use these actions words for subtraction?

Tags: language-use, arithmetic-operations

Do the following sentences express 5-2?

```
a. 5 fewer 2 is 3
b. 2 fewer than 5 is 3
c. 5 less 2 is 3
d. 5 gave 2 is 3
```

I also saw online that "shared" can also mean "minus", can someone please give me an example?

Thank you!

Comment: I would say only b, c are acceptable in the US.

Comment: (a) and (d) sound ungrammatical. Maybe there's some dialect I'm not familiar with where "5 fewer 2" or "5 gave 2" are standard, but they don't sound right to me, and I'd be confused if I saw them without context.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it seems to be about certain English vocabulary / grammar, albeit applied to a mathematical concept.

Comment: @brendansullivan07 I think it's about mathematical language and it's very important to use them correctly in class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**From your list**

a) 5 fewer 2 is 3          is never used

b) 2 fewer than 5 is 3     is used

C) 5 less 2 is 3           Can be used but a better usage is 2 less than 5 is 3

d) 5 gave 2 is 3           Should be rewritten as 5 gave 2 leaves 3

**Additional items (not all are action words - verbs)**

e) 2 units **(shorter/slower/lighter) than** 5 units is 3 units

f) How many units **(longer/faster/heaver) than** 2 units is 5 units? It is 3 units longer

g) Bob has 5 apples and **shares** 1 with each of his 2 sisters.  He has 3 apples **left**.

h) Bob has 5 apples. Lisa has 2 apples. Lisa has 3 **fewer** apples than Bob.

i) The **difference of/between** 5 and 2 is 3

j) **Subtract** 2 from 5 and the answer is 3

k) 5 **minus** 2 is 3

l) Bob has 5 apples and eats 2.  There are 3 **remaining** apples. OR There are 3 **left**. OR There 3 apples **left over**

m) 5 d**ecreased by** 2 is 3.

For more words you can search for

> Arithmetic subtraction key words